# Is there any way to disable scrolling in an Android Webview without setting the onTouch?

Tags: android, iframe, webview, scroll

I have a webview that displays a complex page with a bunch of iframes in it.

Basically what I want to do is disable the scrolling of the page, but WITHOUT setting an onTouch listener to intercept touch events, because I still need scrolling enabled within the iframes on the page.

I tried:

```
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

and

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

But these only seem to turn off the display of the scroll bars, not actually disable the ability to scroll.

Is there any solution?